# How to use 'requests'?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm a Korean who just started learning Python.
First, I apologize for my English.

I learned how to use beautifulSoup on YouTube. And on certain sites, crawling was successful.
However, I found out that crawl did not go well on certain sites, and that I had to set up user-agent through a search.
So I used 'requests' to make code to set user-agent. Subsequently, the code to read a particular class from html was used equally, but it did not work.

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36'}
url ='https://store.leagueoflegends.co.kr/skins'
response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

for skin in soup.select(".item-name"):
print(skin)
```

---

Here's my code. I have no idea what the problem is.
Please help me.

Comment: "_it did not work_" - please explain.

Comment: Aaah, the classic _"I apologize for my English"_ but then write better than 90% of people on this site. Your English supersede our expectations of any newcomer of this site. I'd say it's superb!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `requests` do not render javascript. instead, it only gives you the "initial" source code of the page. what you should use is a package called [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). it lets you control your browser )Chrome, Firefox, ...etc) from Python. the website won't be able to tell the difference and you won't need to mess with the headers and user-agents. there are plenty of videos on Youtube on how to use it.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you so much for teaching me kindly. I'll try Selenium.